# Coffeescript retry loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a loop like this and it should return and exit the loop if the ajax request was successful, also it should only retry 10 times, but it just iterates the loop 10 times and stops then when the request was successful.

```
retryCount = 0

while (retryCount < 10)
  $.ajax
    type: "GET"
    url: "http://" + proxyURL + "?"
    dataType: "jsonp"
    data:
      url:
        url + "?" + method + "&" + $.param
          parameters: JSON.stringify parameters
    success: (response) ->
      data = response

      console.log "----------"
      console.log "METHOD: " + method
      console.log parameters
      console.log data
      console.log "----------"

      if data.contents.fault
        if data.contents.fault.code is 256
          console.log "fetching new token (" + retryCount + ")"
          fetchNewToken ->
            return callback(data.contents.result)
        else
          console.log "ERROR: " + $.trim(data.contents.fault.message)

      if data.contents.result
        if data.contents.result instanceof Array
          if data.contents.result.length > 0
            return callback(data.contents.result)
        else
          return callback(data.contents.result)
      else
        console.log "retrying " + method + " (" + retryCount + ")"

    retryCount++
```

Comment: It's **asynchronous**, so you cannot use a while-loop. Notice that `success` is a callback *function* - that gets easily lost in coffescript

Comment: Same happens to me when setting `async: false` in the ajax request. What would be an alternative way, to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you didn't got the concept of **asynchronous** programming.

This is what happens:

```
retryCount = 0
# TIMESTAMP 0
while (retryCount < 10)
  # TIMESTAMP 1, 3, 5, ...
  $.ajax
    url: "http://" + proxyURL + "?"
    dataType: "jsonp"
    success: (response) ->
      #TIMESTAMP very later, long after your loop is through

  # TIMESTAMP 2, 4, 6, ...
  retryCount++
```

It should somehow related look like this (just an example, kind of pseudocode):

```
retryCount = 0
loadData = (retryCount, callBack, errorCallBack) ->
  $.ajax
    url: "asdasdasd"
    success: () ->
      callBack someDataYouRecieved
    error: () ->
      retryCount++
      if retryCount is 10
        errorCallBack "got 10 errors"
      else
        loadData retryCount, callBack


loadData retryCount, successHandler, errorHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, a construct like this should do the trick (left out domain-specific parts):

```
MAX_RETRIES = 10

issueRequestWithRetries = (request, retries=0) ->
  request.success = (response) ->
    # do something, then find out that you need to retry
    if retries < MAX_RETRIES
      issueRequestWithRetries(request, retries+1)
    else
      # handle the error
  $.ajax request

# sample usage
issueRequestWithRetries
  type: "GET"
  url: "http://" + proxyURL + "?"
  dataType: "jsonp"
  data: {} # real data
```